# if the user sees a div, it should be stored in the db

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm working on a project with laravel. There advertising ads should be displayed on different pages. So the user will see advertisements on different pages. About Ajax I would like to send the data (which was seen advertising) to the database and then save. Is there a command or something similar with which I can trigger the Ajax command as soon as the user has seen the div with the advertisement?

For Example:

```
  <div id=“ad_23“>
// here is an Image or only text 
</div>
```

Comment: To make this work you need the advertising framework you're using to raise events when an advert is shown to the user which you can hook to. Given the lack of information in the question we can't really give you any other help.

Comment: You added a div with invalid quotes. I'm not sure how that's in any way relevant, or adds any useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is short explanation :

With jquery you send data with ajax function :

```
if($('#ad_23').is(":visible")){

    $.ajax({
    data : 'content=' + $('#ad_23').html(),   
    url : '/storedata', 
    type : 'POST' 
    });
}
```

With Laravel you store the data (this example is in routes/web.php) :

```
Route::post('storedata',function(Request $request){


    $content = $request->input('content');

    $result = DB::table('TABLE_NAME')->insert(
    ['content' => $content]
);

    echo $result;
    exit;

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explantation. How do i send the Ajax command if the div is seen?

Comment: I changed my answer, to see if seen, i had if($('#ad_23').is(":visible"))